# Can I get editLink and aclLink by using google calendar api v3 python?

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, google-api-client, google-api-python-client

My current project use gdata and I can easily get editLink and aclLink by following calls:

```
calendar.GetEditLink().href
calendar.GetAclLink().href
```

Now I'm trying to switch to api v3. And I found no way to get editLink and aclLink in v3 API.

```
{
  'kind': 'calendar#calendarListEntry',
  'foregroundColor': '#000000',
  'description': 'FDSA FDS',
  'colorId': '24',
  'summary': 'C Forgie Geography - 201213',
  'etag': '"FDSA4321FDSA/Stic5525eNCO8rFKLA656Xshysg"',
  'backgroundColor': '#a47ae2',
  'timeZone': 'UTC',
  'accessRole': 'owner',
  'id': 'FDSA4321@group.calendar.google.com'
}
```

Is there a way to get editLink and aclLink in v3 API ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: How are you using these values? Is this still relevant?

Comment: Hi, @bossylobster, we display the link in a web page so user can navigates to the calendar page. Thanks!

Comment: Got it, then these are important to have :) I believe these can be constructed using values from the payload but am no calendar expert.

Comment: It's feasible to construct using values from payload. My concern is that it's fragile. If Google change the URL for each calendar, my constructed link will be broken immediately.